# Posting attachments to Slack API

Tags: slack-api, slack

So I just understood that the [Slack Web API](https://api.slack.com/web) does **not** support JSON data over POST. Which means I have to encode my complex and nested JSON object to fit in query parameters over GET. Problem is, the attachements don't seem to work. Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I just understood that the Slack Web API does not support JSON data over POST. Which means I have to encode my complex and nested JSON object to fit in query parameters over GET.

I'm not sure I follow what you mean. You can certainly use POST. The body of a Slack API call should be form-encoded, but parameter values are sometimes JSON (as is the case for `attachments`).

Here's a working `curl` command that uses HTTP POST to post a message with a simple attachment.

```
$ curl -d token=<REDACTED> -d channel=<REDACTED> \
  -d text="This is the main text." \
  -d attachments='[{"text": "This is an attachment."}]' \
  https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
```

I'd recommend using POST, but GET also works fine. If you fill in the values in https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test, the tool will give you a URL at the bottom that you can use with HTTP GET.